# Ordering local storage score in an ascending order

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, local-storage

I want the data in the table to be in an ascending order, so the person with the highest score should be at the top of the table, and the person with the lowest score to be at the bottom of the table. I've created an array and used a for loop to order the data, but nothing displays on the table. I've created a JSFiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/MuddasarAshfaq/8smcc9wj/)

```
/* Rank Table */
function displayTable() {
    var data = []; 
    data = {firstName: data.FirstName, lastName: data.LastName, topScore: data.Score};
    var getData = function(key){return JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);}
    var highScoreTable = "<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Score</th></tr>\n";
    for (var key in localStorage) {
        if (key !== 'loggedInUser') {
            data = getData(key);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                highScoreTable += "<tr><td>" + data[i].firstName + "</td><td>" + data[i].lastName + "</td><td>" + data[i].topScore + "</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('rankTable').innerHTML = highScoreTable;
}
```

Comment: You should not use "all localstorage keys except `loggedInUser`" to store the highscore. Instead, use one `localStorage.highScore` key where you store a (JSON-encoded) array of all the entries.

Comment: I am the storing the highscore in `localStorage[Username]`

Comment: Yes, I see. Don't do that. What if a user chooses "loggedInUser" as his name? Store the highscores in their own, independent collection (either as an array or object keyed by username)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things are wrong with your implementation, kindly see below for change I made to your code:

```
/* Register */
function storeUserDetail() {
  const fNameInput = document.getElementById("firstNameInput").value;
  const lNameInput = document.getElementById("lastNameInput").value;
  const uNameInput = document.getElementById("userNameInput").value;
  const pWordInput = document.getElementById("passWordInput").value;
  const yourScoreInput = document.getElementById("scoreInput").value;

  const storeDetails = {
    firstName: fNameInput,
    lastName: lNameInput,
    username: uNameInput,
    password: pWordInput,
    score: yourScoreInput
  };

  const username = storeDetails.username;

  // save details to localStorage using username as key
  localStorage[username] = JSON.stringify(storeDetails);
}

/* Log In */
function loginUser() {
  const username = document.getElementById("uNameInput").value;
  const password = document.getElementById("pWordInput").value;
  const storeDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage[username]);

  storeDetails.username = document.getElementById("uNameInput").value;
  storeDetails.password = document.getElementById("pWordInput").value;

  localStorage.loggedInUser = username;
}

const data = [];

const getData = key => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
};

/* Rank Table */
function displayTable() {
  let tableBody = '';
  const tableHeader =
    "<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Score</th></tr>\n";

  for (let key in localStorage) {
    if (key !== "loggedInUser") {
      data.push(getData(key));
    }
  }

  for (let user of data) {
    if (tableBody) {
      tableBody +=
        `<tr><td>
        ${user.firstName}
        </td><td>
        ${user.lastName}
        </td><td>
        ${user.score}
        </td></tr>`;
    } else {
      tableBody = 
        `<tr><td>
        ${user.firstName}
        </td><td>
        ${user.lastName}
        </td><td>
        ${user.score}
        </td></tr>`;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("rankTable").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("rankTable").innerHTML = tableHeader + tableBody;
}
```

You can view full source [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BmXYya).

Comment: The output on the table comes out wrong, it displays the data twice

Comment: I tested the code, and whenever I register a new user, the data comes out twice on the table

Comment: Yeah I checked the local storage, and I registered the user only once

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EOGIK -> Image to show that the data comes out twice, even though I've registered each user once

Comment: I've fixed the repetition. Check my code here or on codepen.

Comment: Do I need a for loop? Because you removed it on your updated code

Comment: I only removed it from inside the outer loop. I separated them.

Comment: oh okay, but what does the for loop do?

Comment: I used it to create the table body contents.

Comment: What can I use to order my table for the scores?